# Endless UITableview Section

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a table view with one section.  I pull the data down from the internet in small chunks asynchronously in the background.  The problem I have is I don't know how many records there will be in total.  When the web service stops returning data I know I have them all, in some cases the rows might be infinite.

The method:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

is understandably called once at the beginning of view load, at this point I don't know how big my section is going to be.  Any ideas on how best to approach this problem?  Can I set the section size anywhere after this method has been called?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make the tableview reload it's data, call

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

...and it will ask the datasource about number of rows etc again.

Comment: Will that make the view reload, starting the scroll at the top again?

Comment: Just tried it, looks like it doesn't so this might work.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You say data is pulled in chunks - so only update your table in chunks.

Each time a chunk is downloaded, reload the table. This way, you know how many rows there are after each chunk is finished.

Example:

1. App loads (no data)
2. Chunk downloads

   - Put results into array
   - 6 rows in array, return `[array count]` in number of rows in section method
   - reload table
3. repeat step 2 until done.

Reload data does not reset the scroll position.